# How do I create a new object from states in React with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a state in react containing an array of files. How can I create a new object of type DocumentRequestModel instead? This is what I got so far. documents is my state containing my files.

```
export class DocumentRequestModel implements IDocumentRequestModel {
Data!: string;
FileName!: string;
...
```

This is what I got so far but I get the error message: Type '(string | undefined)[][] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DocumentRequestModel'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'DocumentRequestModel'.

```
const documentModel: DocumentRequestModel = documents?.map(document => [
  document.preview,
  document.name
]);
```

This is how documents look.

```
  0: File
    name: "BOM_BR4666_PROJECTTYPE F_04_06_2020.xlsx"
    lastModified: 1586170093516
    lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 06 2020 12:48:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
    webkitRelativePath: ""
    size: 3948
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    preview: "blob:http://localhost:4000/6d4be14b-0c09-45f9-b2c3-50
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the actual question. Can you explain more? What is your output expectation?

Comment: @acbay I have edited the question. My goal is to create a new DocumentModel of type DocumentRequestModel but I get the errors above.

Comment: First of all, documents can be undefined so is documents is undefined, documentModel be also undefined. Use should the check is documents defined before assignment, means you can be remove the question mark from `documents?.map...`. After that you should have a constructor for your class or just use an interface instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

`const [docModel,setDocModel] = React.useState<DocumentRequestModel>()`

or you want to defined it in array

`const docModel = new Array<DocumentRequestModel>()`

and in you mapping, the documents might be undefined. You might wanna check if it is not undefined before you call the map function

```
const documentModel: Array<DocumentRequestModel> = documents && documents.map(document => [
  document.preview,
  document.name
]);
```